# location directives confusion in nginx configuration

Tags: nginx

I want to have a location directive for the url "localhost/test/" in the nginx configuration.

I tried the following in the configuration file:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;
location /test/ {
root /home/test;
index index.html index.htm
}
```

}

This always give me a 404 error. Then i tried this one

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;
location / {
root /home/test;
index index.html index.htm
}
```

}

It just works fine on url "localhost"

I can't understand why it throws a 404 error in the first case !!

Comment: Did you try localhost/test, removing the final '/'?

Comment: Can you just make root as alias in /test/ case and update me

Comment: nope the same thing !!

Comment: i used location /test/ {
alias /home/test;
index index.html index.htm
}

Comment: You add dummy / and try with root in /test/.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34435/discussion-between-benerd-and-karthikeyan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the obvious issues with your configuration is that alias must be used rather than root

```
location /test/ {
    alias /home/test/;
}
```

because, root makes nginx to search for /home/test/test as per your config.